# prime-hashing: proving that hash-function is collision-free

Tags: functions

Let $U = \{1, \dots, |U|\}$ and $p$ be a prime. Let $h : U \to \{0, \dots, p-1\}$ with $h(u) = (3 \cdot u) \bmod p$.

Prove that if $p > |U| \geq 4$, then $h$ is injective.

The problem comes from Computer Science where I need to show that the hash-function $h$ is collision-free, which amounts to just proving that it is injective. I know I need to show that $h(u) = h(u') \implies u = u'$ ($u, u' \in U$). Now I am stuck with $(3 \cdot u) \bmod p = (3 \cdot u') \bmod p$.

From that, how do I show that $u = u'$, using the fact that $p > |U| \geq 4$ and p is a prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct proof.

If $3u=3u'\bmod p$ then $3(u-u')=0\bmod p$. But $\gcd(3,p)=1$ (because $3$ and $p>4$ are prime, hence share no factors) so $(u-u')$ must be a multiple of $p$.

But $1\le u,u'\le|U|$, so $-|U|<u-u'<|U|$, and importantly
$$-p<u-u'<p$$
and the only multiple of $p$ satisfying this is $0$. Thus $u=u'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $i \in \{1, \dots, p-1\}$ and $j \in \{1, \dots, (p-1)-i\} \cup \{-1, -2, \dots, 1-i\}$.

It follows:

$h(i+j)
= (3 \cdot (i + j)) \bmod p
= (3i + 3j) \bmod p
= ((3i) \bmod p + 3j) \bmod p
= (h(i) + 3j) \bmod p
\neq h(i)$

The inequality is true because $3j$ does not contain $p$ in its prime factorization. After all, $p > 3$ and $p > j$, so that $j$ does not contain $p$ in its prime factorization. By the definitions of $i$ and $j$ it follows that $h(u) \neq h(u')$ for $u, u' \in U$ with $u \neq u'$. This proves injectivity.

Comment: If anyone has a simpler solution, a correction or a suggestion to compress this proof, it would be appreciated.